# Spring Batch step not executing

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am working on a spring batch project in which I am reading a list of students, processing it and writing it.

For now I have kept it simple and processing just returns the student and write just prints it.

I was expecting every-time the step runs I will see the output but I see it only once when the step runs for the first time. Below is the output

```
2020-04-03 01:33:16.153  INFO 14710 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [xxxx]
[Student{id=1, name='ABC'}]
as
[Student{id=2, name='DEF'}]
as
[Student{id=3, name='GHI'}]
as
2020-04-03 01:33:16.187  INFO 14710 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [xxxx] executed in 33ms
2020-04-03 01:33:16.190  INFO 14710 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=readStudents]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 52ms
job triggered
2020-04-03 01:33:17.011  INFO 14710 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=readStudents]] launched with the following parameters: [{time=1585857797003}]
2020-04-03 01:33:17.017  INFO 14710 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [xxxx]
2020-04-03 01:33:17.022  INFO 14710 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [xxxx] executed in 4ms
2020-04-03 01:33:17.024  INFO 14710 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=readStudents]] completed with the following parameters: [{time=1585857797003}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 11ms
```

Also I notice that first time there are no parameters in job and after that there are parameters. Whereas I am supplying job parameters whenever I run job.

Config file

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class Config {

  private JobRunner jobRunner;

  public Config(JobRunner jobRunner){
    this.jobRunner = jobRunner;
  }

  @Scheduled(cron = "* * * * * *")
  public void scheduleJob() throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
    System.out.println("job triggered");
    jobRunner.runJob();
  }
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class JobConfig {
  @Bean
  public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
                 StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                 ItemReader<Student> reader,
                 ItemProcessor<Student, Student> processor,
                 ItemWriter<Student> writer) {

    Step step = stepBuilderFactory.get("xxxx")
        .<Student, Student>chunk(1)
        .reader(reader)
        .processor(processor)
        .writer(writer)
        .build();

    return jobBuilderFactory
        .get("readStudents")
        .start(step)
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public ItemReader<Student> reader() {
    return new InMemoryStudentReader();
  }
}
```

Job runner file

```
public class JobRunner {

  private Job job;
  private JobLauncher simpleJobLauncher;

  @Autowired
  public JobRunner(Job job, JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
    this.simpleJobLauncher = jobLauncher;
    this.job = job;
  }


  public void runJob() throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
    JobParameters jobParameters =
        new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
    simpleJobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);

  }
}
```

In memory student reader

```
public class InMemoryStudentReader implements ItemReader<Student> {

  private int nextStudentIndex;
  private List<Student> studentData;

  public InMemoryStudentReader() {
    initialize();
  }

  private void initialize() {
    Student s1 = new Student(1, "ABC");
    Student s2 = new Student(2, "DEF");
    Student s3 = new Student(3, "GHI");

    studentData = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(s1, s2,s3));
    nextStudentIndex = 0;
  }

  @Override
  public Student read() throws Exception {
    Student nextStudent = null;

    if (nextStudentIndex < studentData.size()) {
      nextStudent = studentData.get(nextStudentIndex);
      nextStudentIndex++;
    }

    return nextStudent;
  }
}
```

Comment: what is inside of InMemoryStudentReader?

Comment: @IharSadounikau Added InMemoryStudentReader

Comment: `nextStudentIndex` is your problem please remove counter and try :)

Comment: @IharSadounikau Then how do I know which student to return? I  mean now   I increment counter so that next time I read I know which student to return.

Comment: You can use pagination for example :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are calling `initialize()` in `InMemoryStudentReader` constructor. Spring only initialize InMemoryStudentReader once and wire it to your job. After the first run, `nextStudentIndex` is not reset to 0. So the next time your job runs, your reader cannot read anymore.

If you want it to work, you should reset the `nextStudentIndex` to 0 whenever you start your job.